# My motor heating too much and very quickly

Tags: current, dc, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I have 48 v 42 amp battery and 1.5kw 55A bldc motor which is operate on controller of 48v 60amp, I am using this in electronic vehicle with gear ratio 1:2, my problem is my motor heating too quickly, why this happening?

Comment: It's happening because the losses in your motor exceed the capability of the motor and whatever cooling provisions you have to dissipate the heat.  Other than that it's impossible to say without more detail.

Comment: BLDC's overheat because the current is too high. Add a fan or reduce the current.

Comment: If you need more torqe, AND your motor is overheating, then either your controller is doing something weird, or your motor is undersized for the mechanical load. You really do need to step back and learn more about motors or answer the questions people are putting in the comments. Answer by editing the question, not by adding comments. And delete one of your two very similar questions.

Comment: -1 you already have a question on this topic **DO NOT REPOST**.

Answer (score 0):

You must realize that motors draw up to 10x the steady state rated current during full start-stop.

So controllers must be rated far more than the motor full RPM load rated current.  I suggest 5x. rated current and/or have soft start controller limit acceleration.

I suggest you review how current is sensed and limit the current demand somehow to stay within operating specs.

...or look at liquid cooling heat exchanger from PC's ;)

Comment: This really depends on the controller.

Comment: Two failure modes : mis-application and under-rated drivers. I always choose motor drivers capable of 5x rated motor current for the above reasons, but in this case, he may have chosen them for cost reasons and is seeing thermal problems with long inertial times to full speed.

Comment: What I mean is that there are a large number of BLDC control strategies. It is not always the case that startup current is 10x steady state.

Comment: agreed, thats why I said "up to" ... but in any case either the RdsOn specs are too high for his controller or poor cooling design